# How to get camera position with mouse move event and transform into screen coordinates in three.js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, three.js, mouseevent

Actually i don't know whether is it possible or not but i want to get my camera positions with mouse move event and transform them into screen coordinates. To be more detailed i am trying to move on my sphere object with mouse and trying to get the corresponding new camera position with mouse move and wanted to update the object position on the google maps. i found some sources how to convert 3D object position into 2-D but i am not sure whether it suits to my scenario.

["I am adding the solution for the problem below in the comments section and i hope it could be useful to someone, if they have encountered this kind of similar problem. Check the two links below"]

Comment: at least you should include the proper dependencies, so that the fiddle can be executed.

Comment: sorry #Thomas i don't have much knowledge about jsfiddle and that is the reason why i have explained everything in words if you need anything more i can even explain in detail. It could be really greatful if you can help me.

Comment: Please do not work around the jsfiddle.net warning. Instead, heed the advice, and edit your post to *include* a [mcve] of the problem you are describing.

Comment: I have posted my solution for the problem which i have faced. I hope this could be more effective. #Matt, #kryger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you want the point you are looking at your sphere (probably with earth texture) to be shown on google maps google which requires latitude and longitude. Using 2D screen coordinates seems a weird method to me.

Your camera is probably around the sphere which is at the center of the coordinate system. I would transform the camera position to polar/spherical coordinates, which are to angles (radius doesn't matter). Then you almost got the lat and long.

[image: polar coordinates]

Conversion from your camera position (x,y,z): ([Conversion between Spherical and Cartesian Coordinates Systems](https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/conversion-between-spherical-and-cartesian-coordinates-systems/))

[image: phi angle]

[image: theta angle]

You need to swap `y` and `z` in the formulas and the graphic, because in three.js `y` is up (and maybe you need to invert `z`).

Now, you need to tranform `phi` (ranging from `0` to `2*PI`) and `theta` (`0` to `PI`) to longitude (`-180°` to `180°`) and latitude (`-90°` to `90°`), which should rather easy.

Your greenwich meridian on your sphere should face to the positive x-axis.

*(Please correct me, if I'm wrong.)*

Comment: Thanks #Brakebein this is what i am looking for and your reference helped me a lot..

Comment: Based on the reference i found the solution for the problem. To make it more simpler the problem was i should update simultaneously both my Webgl and maps and vice versa when ever my mouse move event is fired. I am sharing the two transformations functions which does this for me. This function updates my position on maps when mouse move event is fired in my Webgl application http://pastebin.com/t7M7PusG

Now the vice versa function http://pastebin.com/JvHYnSRq